# Is it possible to use Twillio messaging to implement posts similar as Facebook posts?

Tags: twilio

We want to have one main topic per page with the chronological order but also we need subtopics for the specific tag (subcategory).

All posts (messages/comments) should be persistent without any deleted comment after some time.

Also, we need real-time notifications.

As the summary of this question, we need to implement a clone of the Facebook commenting (posts) system, is all this possible with Twilio?
https://www.twilio.com/messaging

Did anyone have experience implementing similar use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is absolutely possible to do something like that. Firstly, IP messaging is persistent so messages won't be deleted.

As for whether you can have threaded topics and subtopics the answer is also yes. You can choose to do this one of two ways.

You could make each topic a [channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/channels), then all replies to that topic would be sent to the channel. Alternatively, we just released [message attributes](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/07/new-ip-messaging-features-reachability-message-attributes-and-push-configuration.html) which allow you to store a serialised JSON object of meta data along with every message. Using this, you can store a reference to a message that a new message is in reply to.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Phil, thanks for the feedback. We have looked into Twilio IP Messaging with Twilio Notify and it nicely fits into the whole commenting/notification feature of our web application. The last question I have is related to UI SDK kits for chat and commenting. Do you know about any such kits for web? UI SDK similar to Facebook post comments would be ideal.

Comment: I don't know of any UI Kit off the top of my head like that. However, it might be interesting to look into the [OOCSS Media Object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/) which Facebook use as part of their stream.